# Unity Vector3.Dot wrong return value

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am coding a 2D car racing game in Unity.
Right now i want to check if the car is drifting with the Vector3.Dot function but the if state always return a value unequal one so it always prints the drifttrack. This happens even if the car stands still or the car is driving ahead.

```
//Blickrichtung und Fahrtrichtung stimmen nicht überein
    //Driftspuren werden gezeichnet 
    if (1 != Vector3.Dot(myrigidbody2d.velocity, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)))
    { 
        Instantiate(drifttrack, tireLeft.transform.position, tireLeft.transform.rotation);
        Instantiate(drifttrack, tireRight.transform.position, tireRight.transform.rotation);
    }
```

Comment: This happens due to [single floating point precision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Also make sure both vectors are normalized.

Answer (score 5):

Float are not precise, you will most likely never get 1 but something like 1.00000000001 which is not 1 for a computer.

You need to use a range or approximate:

```
float dot = Vector3.Dot(myrigidbody2d.velocity, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward));
if(Mathf.Approximately(dot, 1f)) { }
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

Unfortunately it does not work.

First I normalized the Vectors:

```
Vector3 velo = myrigidbody2d.velocity;
velo.Normalize();
Vector3 direc = transform.TransformDirction(Vector3.forward);
direc.Normalize();
```

Then I compare both and check if they are unequal:

```
float dot = Vector3.Dot(velo, direc);
if (!Mathf.Approximately(dot, 1f))
    {
        Instantiate(drifttrack, tireLeft.transform.position, 
        tireLeft.transform.rotation);
        Instantiate(drifttrack, tireRight.transform.position, 
        tireRight.transform.rotation);
    }
```

It still instantiate my drifttrack without doing anything.